# Oracle APEX, substitution string not working for APEX Item (Select List from Query)

Tags: html, oracle, oracle-apex

I created an interactive report, which gets populated by Apex Items (Textfield, Select List, etc.), in order to use the report as a dynamic form.

Specifically I'm using the *SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY* function to create a dynamic select list.

When I want to populate the report with data dynamically, I need to be able to adress the different items uniquely, to set their values.

Now the [Oracle Documentation for Apex Items](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aeapi/APEX_ITEM.html#GUID-A111B577-2503-4F4E-962E-192C7D5B5338)  suggests the following syntax for *SELECT_LISTs*:

`SELECT  empno "Employee #", 
    ename "Name",
    APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST(
        p_idx           =>   3,
        p_value         =>   deptno,
        p_list_values   =>   'ACCOUNTING;10,RESEARCH;20,SALES;30,OPERATIONS;40',
        p_attributes    =>   'style="color:red;"',
        p_show_null     =>   'YES',
        p_null_value    =>   NULL,
        p_null_text     =>   '-Select-',
        p_item_id       =>   'f03_#ROWNUM#',
        p_item_label    =>   'Label for f03_#ROWNUM#',
        p_show_extra    =>   'YES') "Department"
FROM  emp;`

The important attributes for what I need, are *"p_item_id"* and *"p_item_label"*.

For those, the documentation says:

> • An HTML ID attribute is generated for each row, where #ROWNUM# is substituted for the current row rownum (p_item_id parameter). (So an ID of 'f03_4' is generated for row 4.)
>
> • A HTML label element is generated for each row (p_item_label parameter).

This should be the same for *SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY* but just to be sure, I tested it with both and neither works.

The Apex Item itself is created fine, but the HTML Tags of the Items do not include the required ROWNUM.

Instead of showing up as `id="f03_4"` as the documentation would suggest, the #ROWNUM# keyword is not substituted for the current row number and simply shows up as 
`<select name="f03" style="color:red;" id="f03_#ROWNUM#">` for the provided example above.

Did i miss anything? Why does it not work the way it was described? We are working with APEX 19.1 and the API for this APEX_ITEM functionality is basicaly the same since Apex 5, so I dont think there was a change.

Any Ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ROWNUM substitution string was meant to be used with tabular forms (which were based on Classic Reports). It still works with Classic Reports, but I don't think it ever worked with Interactive Reports.

Perhaps you could work around this by using p_attributes instead of p_item_id.

```
SELECT  empno "Employee #", 
    ename "Name",
    APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST(
        p_idx           =>   3,
        p_value         =>   deptno,
        p_list_values   =>   'ACCOUNTING;10,RESEARCH;20,SALES;30,OPERATIONS;40',
        p_attributes    =>   'style="color:red;" data-empno="' || empno || '"',
        p_show_null     =>   'YES',
        p_null_value    =>   NULL,
        p_null_text     =>   '-Select-',
        p_show_extra    =>   'YES') "Department"
FROM  emp;
```

Then you'd just modify your JavaScript (assuming that's why you need this) to target the data attribute rather than the id attribute.

You could also use empno with p_item_label to create unique labels if needed too.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me quite a bit and I ended up going with this version:

`select 
level as item_nr,
...
APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY( ... , p_item_id => 'f01_'|| level ||'' ) as "Job/Equipment",
...
from dual
connect by level <= :P3_PERSONAL_COUNT;`